# How do I sync a Yongnuo YN560 III speedlight with a Canon 6D?

Tags: hotshoe-flash, yongnuo, canon-6d

I'm a beginner in photography. My company owns a **Canon 6D** with a **Yongnuo YN560 III speedlight**. I fixed the speedlight perfectly with the Canon 6d hot shoe. Sometimes the speedlight works in some setting (e.g., shutter 30, f/4, Auto ISO), but if  I repeat the same, it won't work.

I set same shutter speed as Canon 6D in speedlight.

Comment: Are you waiting until the ready light is on before attempting to fire the flash? Is the problem the flash not firing? Or not firing in sync? Or black bars on the frame? By shutter 30 do you mean 30s or 1/30s? Where are you setting the shutter speed on the YN-560? (AFAIK, it doesn't have an autothyristor).

Comment: is the shutter setting 30 (as in 30 seconds) or 1/30 (as in one-thirtieth of one second)?

Comment: What do you mean by, " I set same shutter speed as Canon 6D in speedlight?"

Comment: (I) not firing in sync (II) 1/30 (III) Firing Speed in speedlite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Yongnuo YN560 III is not a good flash for a beginner because it is a Manual flash.

It has no communication with the camera and you must set the flash output power manually. Unless you use a Flash Meter to read the flash output, trial and error is the only way to find the correct flash power setting. But then the output power must be changed each time you change the distance to your subject.

You would be better off with an ETTL Auto Flash like the Yongnuo YN468 or YN565.